# How to read data from AG-Grid table without scrolling it in Katalon?

Tags: selenium, scroll, ui-automation, ag-grid, katalon-studio

I am trying to getText from a column in ag-grid table using Katalon Studio. This column is at the end of the table and not visible until scrolled. I have tried using Katalon keywords Scroll to Element and Scroll to position but the scroll is not happening, I can easily getText from the column if I scroll the table manually but otherwise the getText fails with msg "Unable to find element".

[image: This is the ag-grid table which needs to be scrolled till end]

[image: This is the column which I need to getText after scrolling]

How do I achieve this through automation using Katalon?
Kindly please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) uses DOM virtualistaion to vastly improve rendering performance.

As the user scrolls horizontally or vertically, the grid dynamically updates the DOM and renders the additional cells that are required while also removing the cells that are no longer in view.

That is the reason, the elements are not present when you don't scroll them into view.

If you anyways want to load the columns for the rows, you can turn off column virtualisation by setting `suppressColumnVirtualisation=true` at grid level.

Keep in mind that this has performance cost associated with it.

> Reference: [Column Virtualisation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-dom-virtualisation/#column-virtualisation)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply @Paritosh , will look for work around.